# Why doesn't g++ complain when derived class calls pure virtual function of base?

Tags: c++, linker, g++, ld, pure-virtual

I have a class `Base` with a pure virtual function `f()`. Another class `Derived` derives from `Base`. I call `f()` from within `Derived`. And using g++, I get an error from the linker.

```
[agnel@dooku tmp]$ g++ pure_virtual_function_call.cpp 
/tmp/ccGQLHi4.o: In function `Derived::f()':
pure_virtual_function_call.cpp:(.text._ZN7Derived1fEv[_ZN7Derived1fEv]+0x14): undefined reference to `VirtualBase::f()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems to me that the error was caught by the linker. Why didn't the compiler report this error? Why leave it to the linker?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class VirtualBase {
public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

class Derived : public VirtualBase {
public:
    void f(){
        VirtualBase::f();
        cout << "Derived\n" ;
    }
};


int main(){
    Derived d;
    d.f();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the source code? That would make it much easier to understand.

Comment: Please show your example code.  Without that, it will be difficult to answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because pure virtual functions can have definitions and, if they do, you are allowed to call them non-virtually using the syntax `VirtualBase::f()`.

The compiler has no way to tell whether you intend the function to be defined or not, and so the error can only be detected by the linker.

Comment: Example of when a pure virtual can have a definition?

Comment: @AgnelKurian: What do you mean? Any pure virtual function can have a definition.

Comment: I did not know that pure virtual functions can have a definition. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

It's not an error to call a pure virtual function. It's an error to call any function that does not have a definition. A pure virtual function can have a definition.

Comment: Example of when a pure virtual can have a definition?

Comment: @AgnelKurian any time. `class C { virtual void f() = 0; }; void C::f() { }`

Comment: You should add, that only not virtual call is allowed

Comment: The way he is calling the function qualified by the class name it doesn't really matter that it's a virtual function because he is calling it directly, bypassing the virtual function mechanism.

Comment: @Lol4t0 - no, a virtual call is always allowed. That's the most common usage. A virtual call won't hit the definition of the pure virtual, except sometimes from a constructor or destructor.

Comment: @SegFault, it is theoretically possible to call pure virtual function in virtual way and it will result in throwing an exception

Comment: @Lol4t0: No, it's not possible to call a pure virtual function virtually. The closest you can get is it to invoke undefined behaviour by trying to call it virtually from the constructor of an abstract class. And your example doesn't thow an exception; it calls `terminate`, which is how that particular compiler chooses to implement the undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, but it does make the difference. You can still call it directly from constructor & destructor. (in another implantation it trowed, so I should've remembered it, but it doesn't matter in context of discussion)

Comment: @Lol4t0 - calling a virtual function virtually (Phew!) from a constructor or a destructor produces undefined behavior. (Despite what I said above; I just looked it up)

Comment: @Lol4t0: No you can't. You can write code that tries to do that, but it will have undefined behaviour. In the words of the standard, "the effect of making a
 virtual call to a pure virtual function directly or indirectly for the object being created (or destroyed)
from such a constructor (or destructor) is undefined.
"

Comment: @MikeSeymour, now we only have to get _virtual call_ definition. (see 10.3.15 in this context)

Comment: @Lol4t0: No, all we have to do is end this off-topic discussion.